# JdbcTemplate separate transactions created for each query

Tags: sql, spring, jdbc, transactions, jdbctemplate

I'm using jdbc for some sql queries and i wanted to execute all separate queries in one method in one transaction. I tried to set configuration setting only for transaction in one query and read it in another:

```
@Transactional
public void testJDBC()  {
    SqlRowSet rowSet =jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet("select set_config('transaction_test','im_here',true)");
    String result;
    while (rowSet.next()) {
        result = rowSet.getString("set_config");
        System.out.println("Result1: "+result);
    }
    SqlRowSet rowSet2 =jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet("select current_setting('transaction_test',true)");
    String result2;
    while (rowSet2.next()) {
        result2 = rowSet2.getString("current_setting");
        System.out.println("Result2: "+result2);
    }
}
```

But my second query uses other transaction or both queries are not transactional, becouse result looks like this:

```
Result1: im_here
Result2:
```

I dont get it what is wrong here that despite Transactional annotation it is still not transactional.

Here are my beans setting:

```
    @Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
    return transactionManager;
}
    public BasicDataSource getApacheDataSource(){
    BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
    dataSource.setUrl(getUrl());
    dataSource.setUsername(getEnvironmentProperty("spring.datasource.username"));
    dataSource.setPassword(getEnvironmentProperty("spring.datasource.password"));
}
    @Bean
public JdbcTemplateExtended jdbc(){
    return new JdbcTemplateExtended(getApacheDataSource());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think making sure `@Transactional` annotations are being handled well is the first step in troubleshooting. To do this, add the following settings to `application.properties` (or `application.yml` file). I assume you are using spring boot.

```
logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        transaction:
          interceptor: trace
```

If you run the logic after applying the above settings, you can see the following log message.

```
2020-10-02 14:45:07,162 TRACE - Getting transaction for [com.Class.method]
2020-10-02 14:45:07,273 TRACE - Completing transaction for [com.Class.method]
```

Make sure the `@Transactional` annotation is handled properly by the TransactionInterceptor.

Note: The behavior of the `@Transactional` annotation works on proxy objects. If you call from a method of the same class or create a class directly instead of autowired, the proxy object is not created and hence the `@Transactional` annotation's expected behavior is not applied.

Comment: thanks fora answear. I added logging into application.properties and it think that in console everything look correct:  `2022-07-18 08:24:39.260 TRACE 5159 --- [0.1-4240-exec-5] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Getting transaction for [pl.ada.srv.controller.TestController.testJDBC]
Result1: im_here
Result2: 
2022-07-18 08:24:39.320 TRACE 5159 --- [0.1-4240-exec-5] o.s.t.i.TransactionInterceptor           : Completing transaction for [pl.ada.srv.controller.TestController.testJDBC]`

Comment: its looks like my jdbcTemplate isnt using transaction at all. Object jdbcTemplate is autowired in TestController class. After first query is executed then any changes it has made are immediately commited to database.